# Django CBV DetailView - accessing the object to assign to a context variable?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I want to assign a specific field of an object to another `context` variable. With function based views, this is simply a matter of declaring the key:value pairs:

```
context = {
  'title': my_object.nick_name
}
```

Now in my template, I can use the variable `{{ title }}` and it'll display the object's field `nick_name`.

How would I achieve the same thing with Class Based Views?

For example, I have this simple DetailView:

```
class MyObjDetail(DetailView):
  model = MyObject

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyObjectDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['title'] = ????? <--- right here
    context['cancel'] = reverse_lazy('my_objs:my_objs_list')
    return context
```

I want to assign the variable `{{ title }}` to be the `nick_name` field of the object being displayed with this class based view. How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview), you'll be able to access the object with `self.object`. Therefore you should do:

```
context['title'] = self.object.nick_name
```

However, you might find it easier to simply access the nickname via the object in the template:

```
{{ object.nickname }}
```

Comment: Lovely! The first method worked (figured it was simple). The second method isn't viable due to how my templates are structured.  I need all views to pass a title variable so I can't do {{ object.nick_name }}